Any ways to run the Ok branch if the result gives Err when matching
I have a match branch that theoretically resolves the Error (if I do have one) condition, which then I would want to execute whatever code I've written in the Ok() branch above.
Is it possible to do that in Rust?
Example:
let foo: Result<Bar, Error> = some_func();
match foo {
    Ok(bar) => { Something happens here }
    Err(e) => { Resolves error, and execute the Ok() case above }
}


You can use unwrap_or_else to handle errors and replace them with a new bar. Then put the Ok code below it where you're guaranteed to have a bar.
let foo: Result<Bar, Error> = some_func();
let bar = foo.unwrap_or_else(|e| {
    // Resolve the error and return a replacement `bar`.
    new_bar
});
// Proceed with `bar`.


I don't think you can "jump" to another match arm, but you can just handle only the Err case first, and then what you had in the Ok case, unconditionally:
let foo: Result<Bar, Error> = some_func();
if let Err(e) = foo {
    // Resolve error
}
// Something happens here

However, this style only works if you don't need to actually use bar.

Yes you could do this.  You would just need a function that they both call.
let foo: Result<Bar, Error> = some_func();
match foo {
    Ok(bar) => do_stuff(),
    Err(_) =>  do_stuff(),
}

If you want to perform additional actions in the Err case, you can include those within the match block while still calling the common function:
match example_function(&mut count) {
    Ok(result) => do_stuff(),
    Err(_) => { println!("Error!"); do_stuff() },
}

But the short answer is yes, you can call the same code for an Ok or Err.

Missing commas on the first example.  Should have commas after do_stuff()
